# Storyboard auto layout places view in table cell with fixed trailing-to-superview constraint to far left

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, storyboard

I placed an `UIImageView` at the right side of a table view cell and added a trailing constraint to the cell of 20.

Yet the image ends all the way at the left of the cell when I run the app.

My table view controller code is very basic:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SailboatCell", for: indexPath) as! SailboatTableViewCell

    return cell
}
```

The identifier is correct and I also set the class of cell.

I've done auto layout a lot and have no idea what I could be missing here.

On a device the images are on the right side when the app starts but end up on the left on newly created cells when I start scrolling.  Things reset themselves a bit when I put the device in landscape and then portrait again.

No auto layout warnings are printed.

Earlier I had other UI elements on the cell that were nicely placed (left-to-right) as expected. Only the image view acted weird. I deleted all other UI elements to avoid any interference.

[image]

EDIT: I've recreated the cell and all is fine know. No idea what is was.

Comment: Based on the Simulator image you posted, it looks like you're getting a default cell instead of your custom cell. I say this because the separator line is indented the width of your image view --- which doesn't happen if you're using a custom cell. Is this a table view as a subview? Or is it a table view controller? In either case, try deleting the controller and start again with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

It might because you have set `semanticContentAttribute` to `.forceRightToLeft` for the cell or `UIView.appearance()`.

According to Apple document for [semanticContentAttribute](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622461-semanticcontentattribute):

> A semantic description of the view’s contents, used to determine whether the view should be flipped when switching between left-to-right and right-to-left layouts.

Comment: Explain why the layout is fine for the first shown cells on a device. (Also, I checked and I had not accidentally set the semantic.)

Comment: @meaning-matters Seem like you are not friendly enough with the person helping you. How can he explain when you have not even given enough information? Should you give more code first?

Comment: @trungduc There's not more code and this answer didn't cover all details I supplied. I've ask again 4h ago and am awaiting his reply.